# How to make the "rotating animation" change speed at random. Fidget spinner animation.

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

I created this animated fidget spinner for a project.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2tt2mao/450/

Right now i am simply rotating the object by using CSS keyframes.

However I was wondering how I would make the speed change more randomly? For example times where its spinning at a slower rate vs times where it spins at a fast rate.

Here is an example of the type of spin animation i would like: https://68.media.tumblr.com/6b689487196da8bea9d540e203f7cd2e/tumblr_oqapg6uMXW1s5laego1_500.gif

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinnerRotate
{
    from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spinnerRotate
{
    from{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spinnerRotate
{
    from{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One posibility is to nest several containers, and set a different animation for each one - but you can reuse the keyframes between them.

Play with the timing and so and you can get different effects:

```css
div {
   display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;

}

.container {
   margin: 30px;
   animation: rotate 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.container2 {
   animation: rotate 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.container3 {
   animation: rotate 7s ease-in-out infinite;
   animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes rotate {
from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="container2">
<div class="container3">
<div class="inner">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```